# vimrc: checking &ft doesn't work unless "filetype detect" ran 1st

Tags: vim

I'm running OS X 10.9. I downloaded the Python 3.3.3 .dmg file and installed it. I download the vim code (not macvim) via google code (mercurial) and built it with the following commands:

```
./configure --enable-python3interp --with-python3-config-dir=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim74
sudo make install
```

Everything seems to work normally. I mention all this to try to cover my basis in case I've caused my own issue.

What I'm trying to figure out is why when I check the file type with `"if &ft == 'python'`" it only returns true if I run `"filetype detect"` 1st. I am not running `"filetype on"` or any other filetype command. I know Vim correctly recognizes my .py files without the `"filetype detect"` because I can run ":echo &ft" and it returns "python".

Is this normal behavior or did I screw something up in the compile? What makes me think this might not be normal is that every example I can find from example .vimrc files I don't see anyone else running `"filetype detect"`.

Thanks.

Edit: I've tried this with `"filetype on"` before the if statement, without the `"filetype detect"`, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the initial conditional detection of the filetype issue, I also ran into the condition failing when opening a new tab or split. Whatever is within the condition is applied to new buffers regardless of file type when I check with the following:

```
filetype detect
if &ft == 'python' 
    ....
endif
```

The following however is checked correctly with each new buffer load:

```
au BufRead *.py [arguments]
```

as in

```
au BufRead *.py let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
```

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

From `:help filetype-detect`:

```
...
   When filetype detection was off, it will be enabled first, like the "on"
argument was used.
```

So either of these sequences should have the effect of setting `'filetype'` to "python":

```
:filetype on
:e foo.py

:e foo.py
:filetype detect
```

My preference is to add `:filetype on` to my vimrc file, either directly or with something like

```
:runtime vimrc_example.vim
```

Comment: I've tried this with "filetype on" before the if statement, without the "filetype detect", but this doesn't seem to work either. :(

Comment: There are three statements:  `:filetype`, `:e`, and `:if`.  Of course, `:if` comes last.  If you want the `'filetype'` option to be set, AND you want the `:filetype` command after the `:e` command, then you have to use `:filetype detect` instead of `:filetype on`.